# Pandas DataFrame Get Header Names based on values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a  Pandas DataFrame as shown below - I'm using Python Pandas.

```
+------------+---------+---------+----------+--------+
| Movie Name | English | Chinese | Japanese | Korean |
+------------+---------+---------+----------+--------+
| A          |       1 |       0 |        0 |      0 |
| B          |       0 |       1 |        1 |      0 |
| C          |       0 |       1 |        1 |      1 |
| D          |       1 |       0 |        0 |      0 |
| E          |       0 |       1 |        0 |      0 |
+------------+---------+---------+----------+--------+
```

I want to convert it like below, by concatenating Header Names based on values (0 or 1)

**Expected Output**

```
+------------+-------------------------+
| Movie Name |        Languages        |
+------------+-------------------------+
| A          | English                 |
| B          | Chinese, Japanese       |
| C          | Chinese,Japanese,Korean |
| D          | English                 |
| E          | Chinese                 |
+------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for matrix multiplication of `1` and last remove last `,` by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for 2 column `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.set_index('Movie Name')
df1 = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').reset_index(name='Languages')
print (df1)
  Movie Name                Languages
0          A                  English
1          B         Chinese,Japanese
2          C  Chinese,Japanese,Korean
3          D                  English
4          E                  Chinese
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, `melt` then the problem became a `groupby` issue

```
s=df.melt('MovieName').query('value==1').groupby('MovieName').variable.agg(','.join)
df['New']=df.MovieName.map(s)
df
Out[690]: 
  MovieName  English           ...             Korean                      New
0         A        1           ...                  0                  English
1         B        0           ...                  0         Chinese,Japanese
2         C        0           ...                  1  Chinese,Japanese,Korean
3         D        1           ...                  0                  English
4         E        0           ...                  0                  Chinese
[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['langauges'] = (df.eq(1)*df.columns).apply(lambda x : ','.join(x), axis = 1).str.strip(',')
df

 Movie Name English Chinese Japanese    Korean  langauges
0     A       1       0        0          0      English
1     B       0       1        1          0      Chinese,Japanese
2     C       0       1        1          1      Chinese,Japanese,Korean
3     D       1       0        0          0      English
4     E       0       1        0          0      Chinese
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with pandas.Series.str.cat . You can read more about it here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'Movie Name':['A','B','C','D','E'],'English':[1,0,0,1,0],'Chinese':[0,1,1,0,1],'Japanese':[0,1,1,0,0],'Korean':[0,0,1,0,0]})
df=df.replace(1,df.columns.to_series())
df=df.replace(0,np.NaN)
df['Languages']=df[['English','Chinese','Japanese','Korean']].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=","),axis=1)
df=df.drop(columns=['English','Chinese','Japanese','Korean'])
```

Result:

```
  Movie Name                Languages
0          A                  English
1          B         Chinese,Japanese
2          C  Chinese,Japanese,Korean
3          D                  English
4          E                  Chinese
```